# Submit button doesnt submit form but checks the validations

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, prototypejs, scriptaculous

The submit button works only for validating the javascript in the question.js file, but it doesnt do the basic function, which is submiting the form itself! Your help is very appreciated.

`***Ruby page code containing the form element***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    loadScript("/javascripts/questions.js",function() {});
</script>

<h1 class="hdr1">Ask question</h1>

<%= link_to Profile.find(session[:user_id]).firstname,{},{:id=>"person"} %>
<% form_for(@question) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>

<br>

<table id="newQuesTable" width="100%" cellpadding="5" border="1">
<tr>
    <td width="25%"><label>Your Question </label> - </td>
    <td><%= f.text_area :content, :rows=>5, :cols=>35, :maxlength=>500, :id=>"newQuesTxtA"%> </td>

<td width="30%"><i><label id="newQuesLabel" style="color:red;background-color:yellow;visibility:visible;"></label></i></td>

</tr>


<tr>
    <td width="25%"><%= f.label :tags %> -</td>
    <td><%= f.text_field :tags, :maxlength=>48, :id=>"tagsNewQuesTxt" %></td>
    <td width="30%"><i><label id="nquesTagsLabel" style="color:red;background-color:yellow;visibility:visible;"></label></i></td>
</tr>


<tr>
    <td>Question Scope -</td>
    <!--the open id for the hierarchy comes here-->
    <!-- the select box comes here -->
    <td> <%= f.text_field :ID_string %></td>
</tr>

</table>

<br>
    <%= f.submit 'Post Question' %> &nbsp; <%= f.submit 'Cancel', :id=>'docNewCancelButton', :type=>'reset' %>

<% end %>

<br>
<hr>
<br>

<%= link_to 'Back', questions_path %>
```

***Javascript code present in question.js file***

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function(){
    $('new_question').observe('submit', submitQuestionCreate);
    $('quesNewCancelButton').onClick('resetquesform')
});

function resetquesform()
{
    event.preventDefault();
    reset($('new_question'));
    return;
}

function submitQuestionCreate(event)
{

    //event.preventDefault();

    var quesfield = $('newQuesTxtA');
    var tagsfield = $('tagsNewQuesTxt');
    var labelnques = $('newQuesLabel');
    var labelnquestags = $('nquesTagsLabel');

    if((quesfield.value == "") && (tagsfield.value == ""))
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        //alert('Question and Tags field cannot be empty');
        labelnques.innerHTML = 'Question field cannot be empty!';
        labelnquestags.innerHTML = 'Please enter (some) relevant tags...';
        probchk = true;
        return;
    }

    if((quesfield.value == "") || (tagsfield.value == ""))
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (quesfield.value == "")
        {
            labelnques.innerHTML = 'Question field cannot be empty!';
            labelnquestags.innerHTML = "";
            probchk = true;
            return;
        }

        if (tagsfield.value == "")
        {
            labelnquestags.innerHTML = 'Please enter (some) relevant tags...';
            labelnques.innerHTML = "";
            probchk = true;


            if (quesfield.value.length > 500)
            {
                labelnques.innerHTML = 'Question too long (should be 500 characters or less)';
                probchk = true;
            }

            return;
        }

    }


    if (quesfield.value.length > 500)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        labelnques.innerHTML = 'Question too long (should be 500 characters or less)';
        probchk = true;
        return;
    }

}
```

---

```
***question controller file***


    # GET /questions/1
      # GET /questions/1.xml
      def show
        @question = Question.find(params[:id])
        if !session[:user_id].nil?
           #@owner = Document.is_owner(params[:id],session[:user_id])
           @fav_count = FavouriteQuestion.count(:all,:conditions=>["question_id = ? AND profile_id = ?",@question.id,session[:user_id]])
           if FavouriteQuestion.count(:all,:conditions=>["question_id = ? AND profile_id = ?",@question.id,session[:user_id]]) > 0
               @fav_status = 1
           else
               @fav_status = 0
           end
        else
           @owner = Document.is_owner(params[:id],nil)
           @fav_status = 0
        end
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # show.html.erb
          format.xml  { render :xml => @question }
        end
      end

      # GET /questions/new
      # GET /questions/new.xml
      def new
        @question = Question.new
        if !session[:user_id].nil?
          @question.profile_id = session[:user_id]
        end
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # new.html.erb
          format.xml  { render :xml => @question }
        end
      end
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if you are doing a, ruby on rails form with javascript validations.  While you can do that, I would recommend starting with a basic MVC structure.  I highly recommend running through a some basics that will orient you to this. http://guides.rails.info/ is a great place to start.  I wish that it had been there when I got started, it would have saved me a great deal of pain :)

The you will want to move your validations into the model.

in `app/models/question.rb`

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :question
end
```

more baked in validation options [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html).

then you want to have a controller to respond to your create events.  in `app/controller/question_controller.rb`:

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @question = Question.new
  end

  def create
    @question = Question.new(params[:question])

    if @question.save
      flash[:confirm] = "You have asked a question"
      redirect_to questions_path
    else
      flash[:error] = @question.errors.full_messages.join(",")
      render :action => :new
    end
  end
end
```

And then your `config/routes.rb`

```
map.resources :questions
```

Your form should look similar to what you have:

```
<%= flash[:error] %>
<% form_for(@question) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :content ...
<% end %>
```

the flash is crude, I haven't used it in a while.  I use the [message_block](http://github.com/rubiety/message_block) plugin.  You can also read more about how the flash works [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Flash.html)

There are plugins to shorten some of this, but I recommend cutting your teeth my doing some of this first.  It helps you get oriented.  Best of luck!